# connected region with piecewise smooth curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

why $D=\mathbb{R}^2$ $-\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is not connected but $D=\mathbb{R}^3$ $-\{(x,0,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is connected?( according to the definition of connected regions by piecewise smooth curves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the formal definitions, it may be useful to include the ones you're using.

For some intuition:

> why $D=\mathbb{R}^2$ $-\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is not connected

Imagine the infinite plane and color the $x$-axis red: you cannot go from a point above the $x$-axis to a point below this axis without crossing the red line; right?

> but $D=\mathbb{R}^3$ $-\{(x,0,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is connected?

Now imagine the infinite (three dimensional) space and again, color the $x$-axis (only the axis; not a plane!) red. Can you think of two points that aren't reachable without crossing the red line?